# Spring Boot cipher BadPaddingException: Decryption error

Tags: spring-boot, encryption, keystore, badpaddingexception

I am following an article [here](https://patrickgrimard.io/2016/03/04/encrypting-and-decrypting-configuration-property-values-in-spring-cloud/), where it described how to use a cipher to encrypt spring boot application properties.

So based on the instruction, I downloaded and placed the JCE  Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) files.

Then I created a keystore,

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias mytestkey -keyalg RSA 
  -dname "CN=Web Server,OU=Unit,O=Organization,L=City,S=State,C=US" 
  -keypass changeme -keystore server.jks -storepass letmein 
  -validity 365
```

After that, I copied the server.jks file in the Spring project **resource** folder and add the following properties to the bootstrap.properties file located under **resource** folder as well.

The content of the bootstrap.properties file looks as below:

```
encrypt.key-store.location: classpath:/server.jks
encrypt.key-store.password=letmein
encrypt.key-store.alias=mytestkey
encrypt.key-store.secret=changeme
```

Now when I run the application, I can easily encrypt or decrypt by making POST call to **"http://localhost/encrypt"** and **"http://localhost/decrypt"**  endpoints.

And I can encrypt or decrypt successfully in the code using the **TextEncryptor** as well.

However when I encrypt some value and add the encrypted value to the application.properties, as shown below:

```
messageinfo={cipher}AQBt2RnIRqX1UrHGfvcJpQhfurqbxjGEgeHh....
```

When I run the application again I get

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot decrypt: key=messageinfo
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
```

I am not sure, how I can resolve this issue, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find the issue, it was issue related to **Java environment**, I had multiple Java SDK installed on my box, My **JAVA_HOME (and PATH)** was pointing to **Java 11 SDK**, so when I used the keytool to generate key, it was using **Java 11**.

However in my Spring Studio, it was pointing to **Java 8 SDK**, so when I ran the project it used the **Java 8** to read and decrypt.

So After:

- Uninstalled Java 11
- Changed the JAVA_HOME (and PATH) to point to Java 8 SDK
- Regenerated key using keytool

It started working fine.